# How can I locate an API endpoint?

Tags: api, rest, endpoint

What is the URL for the API endpoint that allows you to get basic information for each listing?

https://pt.airbnb.com/users/#####/listings

Comment: You consult the documentation https://www.airbnb.com/partner

Comment: @RaymondChen how did you conclude this was about airbnb?

Comment: @Evert Good callout. I edited out the original AirBnB URL (because it linked directly to a property and could be interpreted as spammy). I restored it, but used `#####` to avoid getting flagged.

Comment: @RaymondChen ah makes sense now =) should have checked the edits.